# Xcode always crashes when Tunnelblick 3.1.1 connected

Tags: xcode

Xcode works fine if I start it before Tunnelblick (VPN) connected. But it crashes when I start Xcode with Tunnelblick already connected. Has someone had this issue and found a solution?

This is the app crash report:

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: count
ProductBuildVersion: 4A304a
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x200d3e540
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff88da9796 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff838b10f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff88e03110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff88d7b91f ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff88d77a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff88d09228 CFStringFindWithOptionsAndLocale (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff88d091cc CFStringFindWithOptions (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff88d091a0 CFStringHasSuffix (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8161f19e +[NSHost currentHost] (in Foundation)
  9  0x0000000118499bf7 -[XCDistributedBuildLocalHost _allocateHost] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x0000000118496293 -[_XCDistributedBuildHostInfoTask receivedStdoutObjectInBackground:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x0000000118435ede -[XCPosixTaskBackgroundReaderThread backgroundThread:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x00007fff815cbf29 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 13  0x00007fff812dd4f6 _pthread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff812dd3a9 thread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Comment: Solved by disable the vpn set nameserver option.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar crash in a Lexmark printer driver binary, which I described in this [blog post](http://dossy.org/2013/01/debugging-a-strange-macos-x-printing-problem/).

I determined the root cause to be more than one domain name listed in /etc/resolv.conf's "search" parameter.

The reason you may be experiencing this with Tunnelblick, is you may have a "dhcp-option DOMAIN" line in your config.ovpn that specifies more than one domain.  In this case, if you allow Tunnelblick to set DNS (which you discovered disabling would "prevent" the crashes), then the bug in NSHost when it calls CFString will occur.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Xcode is trying to access something on the network, and failing to properly handle the result when you are connected to the Internet through your VPN.

The references to XCDistributedBuildLocalHost may mean that Xcode is trying to do something with distributed builds -- maybe trying to register as an available build worker, or maybe trying to get a list of available build workers, or something like that.

You might want to try unchecking Xcode's distributed build preferences (if they are checked).

By the way, Tunnelblick 3.1.1 has security vulnerabilities. See the [2011-01-27 Tunnelblick Vulnerability FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/wiki/vulnerability20110127FAQ)

Comment: I have no distribution build enabled. And tried update the Tunnelblick to 3.1.6, but still crashing. Thanks all the same!